# Oracle 11g left join issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, left-join, outer-join

Try to create a sample DB like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE "APP" 
   (    "CODICE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   );

Insert into APP (CODICE) values ('A');
Insert into APP (CODICE) values ('B');
Insert into APP (CODICE) values ('C');
Insert into APP (CODICE) values ('D');
Insert into APP (CODICE) values ('E');

CREATE TABLE "APP2" 
   (    "CODICE" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "STATO" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   );

Insert into APP2 (CODICE,STATO) values ('A','E');
Insert into APP2 (CODICE,STATO) values ('B','E');
Insert into APP2 (CODICE,STATO) values ('C','E');
```

Now, try a left join like this:

```
select app.codice codice1, 
    case 
      when app.codice in ('A','B','C') then 'OK'
      when app.codice in ('D','E') then 'KO'
      end azione,
      tt.codice codice2, 
      tt.stato
from app left join (select app2."CODICE", 'E' stato
from app2) tt on app.codice=tt.codice
```

The result is very strange, the column "stato" belongs to the right table, so, in left join, should be null if the right key is null, so if codice2 is null.
For codice=D or E the right table does not match, but the stato column is not null.
It does not occur if you replace the static column 'E' stato with the real column stato in the table app2

Comment: Show us the current result and also the result you want. (Formatted text please.)

Comment: done below.....

Answer (score 0):

You outer join `app2` to `app`. So you select all records from `app` with all their matches in `app2` (as in an inner join) plus records from `app` that have no match in `app2`. And this is exactly what you get

```
CODICE1  AZIONE  CODICE2  STATO
A        OK      A        E
B        OK      B        E
C        OK      C        E
E        KO      NULL     NULL
D        KO      NULL     NULL
```

The `app` records A, B, and C have exactly one match each in `app2`. The `app` records E and F have none.

You'll get the same result for

```
left join (select app2."CODICE", 'E' stato from app2) tt on app.codice=tt.codice
```

and

```
left join (select app2."CODICE", app2.stato from app2) tt on app.codice=tt.codice
```

and

```
left join app2 tt on app.codice=tt.codice
```

of course when all records in `app2` have `stato = 'E'`.

Comment: Yes, your result il what I expect, but is not what I get. My last 2 record have STATO=E. If I remove the case statement I get the correct result. This is my Oracle Version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Works fine for me. same version. See here: http://rextester.com/WOFW4225

Comment: No, it works also for me if you remove the azione column (removing the case), please, try with the case like me...

Comment: Also in sqlfiddle works fine, like rextester, same version. So, maybe the express edition has not a bug that the Enterprise has.....It's strange

Comment: Another test: In "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production" it also works fine. But well, of course it may still be that Enterprise 11.2.0.2.0 has a bug that neither Express 11.2.0.2.0 nor Enterprise 11.2.0.4.0 has.

Comment: 10269193+ Wrong results with outer join and CASE expression optimization (CASE need not to be present) the concrete bug    https://www.eygle.com/Notes/11.2.0.3.html